# Getting Liferay CookieNotSupportedException

Tags: java, cookies, liferay-6, okhttp

When I tried hitting the below url from Chrome Postman, it is hitting successfully and was able to logined with the username and password.

http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login?login=myemail@domain.com&password=mypassword&rememberMe=false

But when I tried hitting the same from a satandalone java program like as shown below I am getting

**SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Main Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.liferay.portal.CookieNotSupportedException]**

My Java code is as given below

```
RequestBody emptyBody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login?login=myemail@domain.com&password=mypassword&rememberMe=false")
    .post(emptyBody)
    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Full Error Code is given below

```
Jan 18, 2017 3:21:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Main Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.liferay.portal.CookieNotSupportedException] with root cause
com.liferay.portal.CookieNotSupportedException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CookieKeys.validateSupportCookie(CookieKeys.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil.login(LoginUtil.java:213)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:93)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:557)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:534)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:361)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:308)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:268)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

:21:19,480 WARN  [http-bio-8083-exec-8][code_jsp:?] {code="500", msg="", uri=/c/portal/login}
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.CookieNotSupportedException
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:557)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:534)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:361)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:308)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:268)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.CookieNotSupportedException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CookieKeys.validateSupportCookie(CookieKeys.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil.login(LoginUtil.java:213)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:93)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    ... 85 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I had just quick look at LoginUtil.java line 213: 
It calls `CookieKeys.validateSupportCookie(request);` which basically looks for cookie with name `COOKIE_SUPPORT`.
If this cookie is not found in request then it throws exception.

You could set below portal properties to false to avoid above check. You have to evaluate effects of this property change.
`#
    # Set this to false to disable all persistent cookies. Features like
    # automatically logging in will not work.
    #
    session.enable.persistent.cookies=true`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you tell me what are the effects if we do this

Comment: It says 'features  like # automatically logging in will not work.'. I am not aware of other effect